# How do I set frame_end in the scene using script when I switch between different actions?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, scene

[image]

I have different animations in each action with different duration.

Is there a way to store the length of the duration in each action so that the frame_end can adjust accordingly to it?

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end = (animationLength * 24)
```

only set my *frame_end* at the last loop in my *for loop* for creating multiple animation.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will loop over all actions and prints the length in keyframes of each action, the scenes keyframe position is adjusted.

```
import bpy

frame=1
for action in bpy.data.actions:
    print( "action=%s" % action.name )
    print( "action length=%d" % action.frame_range.y)
    frame = frame + action.frame_range.y
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set( frame )
    print( "frame=%d" % frame)
```